# How to give the "hello world" at Runtime?

Tags: c++, internationalization, g++, locale, gettext

I am trying to print the "hello world" program in local language and i executed successfully... but now i am trying to do the same by entering hello world @run time... is this possible? and how?
i have followed the following code example...

```
cat >hellogt.cxx <<EOF
// hellogt.cxx
#include <libintl.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main (){
    char* cwd = getenv("PWD");
    std::cout << "getenv(PWD): " << (cwd?cwd:"NULL") << std::endl;
    char* l = getenv("LANG");
    std::cout << "getenv(LANG): " << (l?l:"NULL") << std::endl;
    char* s = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::cout << "setlocale(): " << (s?s:"NULL") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "bindtextdomain(): " << bindtextdomain("hellogt", cwd) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "textdomain(): " << textdomain( "hellogt") << std::endl;
    std::cout << gettext("hello, world!") << std::endl;
}
EOF
g++ -ohellogt hellogt.cxx
xgettext -d hellogt -o hellogt.pot hellogt.cxx
msginit --no-translator -l es_MX -o hellogt_spanish.po -i hellogt.pot
sed --in-place hellogt_spanish.po --expression='/#: /,$ s/""/"hola mundo"/'
sed --in-place hellogt_spanish.po --expression='s/PACKAGE VERSION/hellogt 1.0/'
mkdir -p ./es_MX/LC_MESSAGES
msgfmt -c -v -o ./es_MX/LC_MESSAGES/hellogt.mo hellogt_spanish.po
export LANG=es_MX
ls -l $PWD/es_MX/LC_MESSAGES/hellogt.mo
./hellogt
strace -e trace=open ./hellogt
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? How did it work? How *didn't* it work?

Comment: i am printing all the messages required in required language but i am doing it manually i mean...  you can observe in the that hola mundo is an equivalent spanish sentence for hello world which has been generated externally from poedit... i want to do this @ runtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gettext` is a runtime function. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Interface-to-gettext).

Maybe try this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   if(argc > 1)
       printf("%s\n", gettext(argv[1]));
}
```